# comparing two files and merge the data

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, nawk

I have the below files,

total.txt

`order1,5,item1`
`order2,6,item2`
`order3,7,item3`
`order4,6,item4`
`order8,9,item8`

changed.txt

`order3,8,item3`
`order8,12,item8`

total.txt is total order data and changed.txt is recently changed data. I want to merge the recent change with total, i want the output as ,

Output.txt

`order1,5,item1`
`order2,6,item2`
`order3,8,item3`
`order4,6,item4`
`order8,12,item8`

Note : 2nd column of (3rd & 5th) row of the total.txt is updated with changed.txt file

i have used the below `nawk` to compare the first coulmn, but not able to print it to the output file. Please help on complete the below command

`nawk -F"," 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in a) "print??"' total.txt changed.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Another `awk`

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0;next} {print (a[$1]?a[$1]:$0)}' changed.txt total.txt
order1,5,item1
order2,6,item2
order3,8,item3
order4,6,item4
order8,12,item8
```

---

How does it work?

```
awk -F, '                       # set field separator to ","
    FNR==NR {                   # run this only on first file "changed.txt"
        a[$1]=$0                # store "changed.txt" in array "a" using first field as index
        next                    # skip to next record
    }
        {                       # run this when second file is read "total.txt"
        print (a[$1]?a[$1]:$0)  # if filed exist in "changed" use that, else use "total"
    }' changed.txt total.txt    # read these files
```

Comment: +1 yours, after posted my answer, I found I had same idea with yours. and you gave explanations.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^([^,]*,).*/s|^\1.*|&|/' changed.txt | sed -f - total.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

does this one-liner work for you?

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}a[$1]{$0=a[$1]}7' change total
```

test:

```
kent$  head c t
==> c <==
order3,8,item3
order8,12,item8

==> t <==
order1,5,item1
order2,6,item2
order3,7,item3
order4,6,item4
order8,9,item8

kent$  awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}a[$1]{$0=a[$1]}7' c t
order1,5,item1
order2,6,item2
order3,8,item3
order4,6,item4
order8,12,item8
```

Answer (score 0):

Read first `changed.txt` file and save data in a hash. Then compare if first field of `total.txt` exists in it and replace the value:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," } 
    NR == FNR { a[$1] = $2; next } 
    { if ( $1 in a ) { $2 = a[$1] } print }
' changed.txt total.txt
```

It yields:

```
order1,5,item1
order2,6,item2
order3,8,item3
order4,6,item4
order8,12,item8
```